# Importing css in JSX file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to import css styles into js file, but i cannot use styles properly

in my file `Graph.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Graph.css';
import Center from './Center/Center'

class Graph extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div className={styles.graph}>
                <Center>test</Center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Graph;
```

I try to use style from file `Graph.css`
which looks like this:

```
.graph {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Is there a possibility to manage importing styles to components this way?

Comment: without bundler - no. Use webpack or rollout to manage it

Answer (score 4):

your import statement should be `import './Graph.css';` and in component `<div className="graph">`

Answer (score 4):

You are probably confusing react and react-native.

In react, you don't need to `styles.graph`.

Rather doing the way you do it in normal `.html` file would work

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Graph.css';
import Center from './Center/Center'

class Graph extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="graph"
                <Center>test</Center>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default Graph;
```

Comment: is it even possible to do `import styles` when he don't have `export default styles` in his css?

Comment: That happens through `WebPack`  File Loader plugin`. Javascript in itself does not have the concept of importing and export css or image file using import statement

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important css rule option in your webpack config.

```
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: true,
        camelCase: true
    }
}
```

Add this options object in order to import styles. The modules option let you enable to use your css as a style object and camelCase option enables using "some-class" as someClass.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import file directly i.e `import './Graph.css'` and use it as normal class on div or whenever you want. There are other ways to stlye element such as inline style and more. You can explore more here . https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822 (its great article)